# Writing a recursive function in Python

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

Assume the availability of a function named printStars that can be passed a parameter containing a non-negative integer value. The function prints out the given number of asterisks.

Write a function named printTriangle that receives a parameter that holds a non-negative integer value and prints a triangle of asterisks as follows: first a line of n asterisks, followed by a line of n-1 askterisks, and then a line of n-2 asterisks, and so on.

For example, if the function received 5, it would print

```
*****
****
***
**
*
```

The function must not use a loop of any kind (for, while, do-while) to accomplish its job. The function should invoke printStars to accom;lish the task of printing a single line.

I have the base case worked out I believe. Here is my code:

```
def printTriangle(n):
    if n == 1:
        printStars(n)
```

I need some help figuring out the recursive step. I am thinking it uses n-1 as a parameter, but I am not sure how to call the printTriangle function properly. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's use `n=5` as an example. A 5-row triangle

```
*****    # 5 stars ...
****     # ...followed by a 4-row triangle
***
**
*
```

is just a row of 5 stars, printable with `printStars(5)`, followed by a 4-row triangle, printable with `printTriangle(4)`. Similarly, the 4-row triangle is just a row of 4 stars followed by a 3-row triangle. In general, an `n`-row triangle is just a row of `n` stars, followed by an `n-1`-row triangle. As an old college professor used to tell us, "Trust your recursion", by which he meant, while writing `printTriangle`, assume that `printTriangle` will work correctly and use it when you can. You print an `n`-row triangle by printing a row of `n` stars with `printStars(n)`, followed by an `n-1`-row triangle with `printTriangle(n-1)`. This means that the base case is even simpler: for `n=0`, do nothing! Otherwise, print a row of `n` stars and then recurse on the smaller triangle that follows.

```
def printTriangle(n):
    if n == 0:
        # Base case
        return
    else:
        # Recursive case
        printStars(n)
        printTriangle(n-1)
```

Comment: This works perfectly, but is there a way to add a space or new line character after each printing of the star? The printStars function is already defined so I can't modify that, so I am thinking maybe print(printStars(n),end= '\n')) ?

Comment: No. `printStars` appears to be printing directly to standard output, not returning a string, so you can't really affect how that output appears. (At least, not in any simple fashion. You might redefine `sys.stdout` to capture and modify what `printStars` prints, but that still depends on how `printStars` is implemented and beyond the scope of this question.)

Answer (score 3):

Recursion works by reducing a problem instance characterised by `n` to one characterised by `n-1`. To be finite it has to stop at some instance `n0`.

For this problem `n` is the length of the string.

- So when implementing `f` if you have some function that can handle to print the wanted string of length `n-1`, you will just print one asterisk and then call that function. The trick is that this function is the function `f` itself.
  For a string of length `0` you print nothing and return.

This will yield a recursive function `f` that prints a string of `n` asterisks when called as `f(n)`.

Next you handle the triangle by providing some function `g`.

- It will return and do nothing if it is called with argument `0`.
  Else it will use `f(n)` to print one row, then print the line feed 
  and then call itself with argument `n-1`.

A call of `g(5)` should print the example triangle.

You should use the longer names from your question text for the functions.

Answer (score 1):

Print n stars, reduce n by 1, repeat until n = 0

```
def printTriangle(n):
    if n > 0:
        printStars(n)
        printTriangle(n-1)
```

This function keeps calling itself until n is 0

Comment: Doesn't subtracting one from n and then passing n-1 as a parameter reduce n by 2?

Comment: I would remove the `n -= 1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
def printTriangle(n):
  if n > 0:
    printStars(n)
    printTriangle(n-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The function prints `n` stars, then decrements by calling itself with the parameter `n - 1`. So the base case should be when `n` is equal to 1 because it's illogical to decrement it any further. Decrements only happens when `n` is greater than 1.

So in pseudocode it comes out to:

```
function pstars(n)
    printStars(n)

    if (n > 1)
        pstars(n - 1)
```

See how it calls itself and decrements n?

Spoilers in Python code:

> `def printTriangle(n):
>     printStars(n)
>
>     if n > 1:
>         printTriangle(n - 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Add in a print statement, or some equivalent, to make each recursive step print to a new line.

```
def printTriangle(n):
    if n == 0:
        return
    if n > 0:
        printStars(n)
        print()
        printTriangle(n-1)
```